If $A$ and $B$ are both real symmetry positive definite, then ${\rm tr}(AB^{-1})B-A$ is also positive definite

If $A$ and $B$ are both real symmetry positive definite, then ${\rm tr}(AB^{-1})B-A$ is also positive definite.

This is a linear algebra question that I encountered while studying Kähler geometry.
Note that when $B=I$, this simply means that subtracting one of the eigenvalues from the sum of all eigenvalues of $A$ must be greater than zero.
Generally, suppose $X$ is invertible and $Y$ is orthonormal such that
$$X^TBX=I,\quad Y^T(X^TAX)Y={\rm diagonal~matrix}$$
Then
$$Y^TX^T({\rm tr}(AB^{-1})B-A)XY={\rm tr}(AB^{-1})I-{\rm diag}({\rm ~eigenvalues~of~}X^TAX).$$
We need to show that
$${\rm tr}(AB^{-1})I-{\rm diag}({\rm ~eigenvalues~of~}X^TAX)$$
is also positive definite. But I don't know how to deal with ${\rm tr}(AB^{-1})$. I don't know what the trace of the product of two matrices means, which makes me stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Multiplying on the right and left by $B^\frac{-1}{2}$ effects a congruence transform and it suffices to show
$\text{trace}\big(AB^{-1}\big)\cdot I - B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}=\text{trace}\big(B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}\big)\cdot I - B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}\succ \mathbf 0$
The first equality is cyclic property of trace and the right hand side is immediate since $\big(B^\frac{-1}{2}AB^\frac{-1}{2}\big)\succ \mathbf 0$ hence its trace (Schatten 1 norm) is strictly bigger than its largest eigenvalue (Schatten $\infty$ norm)
